# ASW SES not sending emails with no-reply@my.domain

Tags: email, amazon-ses

I have a verified domain configured in SES. When I send an email with no-reply@my.domain, SES is not sending the email. If I use a valid email address from that domain, SES delivers them.

Does anyone know why this is happening? If my memory doesn't fail me, this used to work just fine as I've had this setup for years. Did something change recently in the AWS SES service?

I have looked for any mention regarding this and all I found is that the domain needs to be verified which it is.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you still in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS SES documentation, such emails are hight not recommended

> Avoid using a no-reply address, such as no-reply@example.com, as your
> "From" or "Reply-to" address. Using a no-reply@ email address sends
> your recipients a clear message: that you aren't offering them a way
> to contact you, and that you're not interested in their feedback.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/tips-and-best-practices.html

Comment: I don't understand why. Is there a better service to use to send password resets and welcome emails from?

Comment: we recommend Sendgrid for your case, SES is also very aggressive about bounces

Comment: Meanwhile, AWS themselves send me email from `no-reply@amazonaws.com`, `no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com`, `no-reply@verify-signin.aws`, `no-reply-aws@amazon.com`...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the domain being verified, the sender email address that you want to use should be verified too. AWS will send you a mail to this address to confirm that it exists. If it doesn't exist, you can create a email receiving rule that will save the email into S3. You can then dig the verification link from there.